# Jquery scrollLeft scrolling to random places

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am trying to use scrollLeft to animate scrolling a horizontal div

I cannot work out what I am doing wrong - the month links along the bottom should take you to its corresponding div in the horizontally scrolling div, it works sometimes but most of the time goes to random places (particularly going backwards)

It is easier to demo than explain so please find below a js fiddle. Beneath that is the js

As ever, any advice is gratefully received - If you need any more info please let me know

http://jsfiddle.net/6J9Cc/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

 $(".timenav a.may").click(function(){

      $('.hori').animate({scrollLeft:$('#may').position().left}, 800);

  });

   $(".timenav a.june").click(function(){

      $('.hori').animate({scrollLeft:$('#june').position().left}, 800);

  });

    $(".timenav a.july").click(function(){

      $('.hori').animate({scrollLeft:$('#july').position().left}, 800);

  });

    $(".timenav a.august").click(function(){

      $('.hori').animate({scrollLeft:$('#august').position().left}, 800);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that when you get the *[position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)*, you're getting it relative to the parent. When you click "June" initially, the left position is 800, but after it's done scrolling, the left position for June is now 0. When you scroll to zero you end up at the start.

The solution I came up with was to just save all those 'left' positions into an array at the beginning. You may also want to consider using [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), which is a position relative to the document.

Here's my solution, with a few other things cleaned up: http://jsfiddle.net/BUyzY/1/

```
var posLeft = [
    $('#may').position().left
    ,$('#june').position().left
    ,$('#july').position().left
    ,$('#august').position().left
];
var $hori = $('.hori');

$('.timenav a').on("click",function(e){
    $this = $(this);
    $hori.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: posLeft[ $this.data("month") ]
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. +1. FYI to both of you, both original and solution are currently problematic in both Opera and IE because of display:table-cell for IE and neither of them animate.